# how to see the values of a json in a tap

Tags: angular, rxjs

when I do something like

```
tap(_ => {console.log('returned contact ' + _)}),
```

I see results like:

```
returned contact object/object
```

I would like to inspect the values of the json

but when I do:

```
updateContact(contact: Contact): Observable<Contact>{
    console.log('starting ContactService.updateContact ID' + contact.id + ' name ' + contact.name);
    return this.httpClient.put(this.url, contact, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(
        tap(x => {let contact: Contact;
                  contact =  x.body;
                  console.log('returned contact ' + contact.id + ' '+ contact.name + ' ' + contact.email + ' ' + contact.address)}),
        map(x => {return x.body as Contact;})
    );
  }
```

I cannot seem to get the body which holds the contact JSON to view the values the line

```
contact =  x.body;
```

returns an error of

```
ERROR in src/app/service/contact.service.ts(40,23): error TS2696: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Contact': "id", "name", "email", "address"
```

my question is within a tap is there a way to view the values within the JSON?
I tried doing a cast etc. however it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I was looking for:

```
  updateContact(contact: Contact): Observable<Contact>{ // must be called with a subscribe to work, an An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method.
    console.log('starting ContactService.updateContact ID' + contact.id + ' name ' + contact.name);
    return this.httpClient.put(this.url, contact, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(
        tap(x => {          
          //let contact: Contact;
                  let contact: Contact = x.body as Contact;
                  console.log('x.body ' + x.body)
                  console.log('returned contact ' + contact.id + ' '+ contact.name + ' ' + contact.email + ' ' + contact.address)
                }),
        map(x => {return x.body as Contact;})
    );
  }
```